# HTML5 Fullscreen API & performance

Tags: performance, fullscreen, html5-video

I'm coding an app around video content and am currently playing around with HTML5's fullscreen API (I know it is still in very early stage).

Because of what my application does, the video itself isn't the only part that goes fullscreen: several elements alongside go fullscreen too, and I have noticed a great drop in performance there. The video streams ok, but other graphical elements suddenly get painfully slow. For example, a hover style typically takes about a good half second before showing up. A simple change in subtitles (I use popcorn.js) causes the video to freeze for a fraction of a second.

**Any one knows why this is so? Do you experience the same?** Thanks for your precious feedback.